# Установка языковых пакетов для tesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, tesseract

Я столкнулся с проблемой: модуль teseract для python распознает английский язык, но не распознает русский. Мне не удалось найти мануал о том, как надо правильно установливать языковой пакет. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Операционная система: Windows x64

Язык: Python 3.7.4

Answer (score 2):

Во время установки тессеракта нужно выбрать опцию `Additional language data` и выбрать нужные языки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вручную [дозагрузить файл языка](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) и бросить его в папку `Tesseract-OCR\tessdata`.

Comment: А как эта же проблема решается для Mac сейчас?

Comment: @malesya я не знаю.